# Magento system log filling up with CSS and JS debug messages

Tags: magento-1.8, log, debug, logging

My Magento log is filling up with inlcusions of JS and CSS files (400 mb in couple of days) - what can this be?

I don't recall putting in any debug statements ...

Quite annoying

Where to start looking (Magento 1.8.1)

```
2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): scriptaculous/slider.js
2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)

2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): varien/js.js
2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)

2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): varien/form.js
2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)

2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): mage/translate.js
2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)

2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): mage/cookies.js
2014-05-30T19:03:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could throw a `mageDebugBacktrace()` into `Mage.php`'s log function to see what is calling `Mage::log`.  Wouldn't recommend it in a live environment, though.